# How can I open and copy specific data from excel files and append them into a single excel file?

Tags: python, excel, matrix, append, transpose

The following code shows the current program that creates an excel file called "OUT.xlsx" which is a matrix created from combining the second column all rows of every excel file in a specific file directory. Ignore this information to avoid confusion because this is just an explanation of what the current program does.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

def clearvars():    
    for el in sorted(globals()):
        if '__' not in el:
                print(f'deleted: {el}')
                del el
clearvars() 

fileDir = Path("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test")
outfile = Path(fileDir, 'OUT.csv')
fileNames = sorted(fileDir.glob('*.csv'))

second_col= []

for file in fileNames:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    second_col.append(df.iloc[:, 1])

matrix = np.array(second_col)
np.savetxt(outfile, matrix, delimiter=",")
```

Building on from the current program, I want to transpose the "OUT.xlsx" matrix. I then want to copy the 0th column and all rows (wavenumber data) from the first excel file in the "Test" file directory ("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test"). I then want to transpose this data and append it to the "OUT.xlsx" matrix along the 0th row and all columns.
Finally I want to append specific string names such as "Cat" to the 0th column all rows reading "Cat" to the "OUT.xlsx" excel file. After this step the "OUT.xlsx" file created from the program should contain these modifications.

Thanks!

Comment: please provide some sample data/code

Comment: @gold_cy. I'll re-edit my question to show my current code. I'm not sure how to provide sample data though.

Comment: @gold_cy, the post has been re-edited. Would you mind having a look at some examples of code I should do? Thanks